# VIM line count in status bar with thousands separator?

Tags: vim, statusbar

Is it possible to display the line count in the VIM status bar with thousands separators, preferably custom thousands separators?

Example:

```
set statusline=%L
```

should lead to "1,234,567" instead of "1234567".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a way but it looks a bit crazy:

```
set statusline=%{substitute(line('$')\,'\\d\\zs\\ze\\%(\\d\\d\\d\\)\\+$'\,'\,'\,'g')}
```

The first round of backslashes is just for `set` (I have to escape `,` and `\` itself).

What I'm actually setting the option to is this string:

```
%{substitute(line('$'),'\d\zs\ze\%(\d\d\d\)\+$',',','g')}
```

As a format string, this line contains one formatting code, which is `%{...}`. Everything in `...` is evaluated as an expression and the result substituted back in.

The expression I'm evaluating is (spaces added (if I had added them to the real code, I would've had to escape them for `set` again, forcing yet more backslashes)):

```
substitute(line('$'), '\d\zs\ze\%(\d\d\d\)\+$', ',', 'g')
```

This is a call to the `substitute` function. The arguments are the source string, the regex, the replacement string, and a list of flags.

The string we're starting with is `line('$')`. This call returns the number of lines in the current buffer (or rather the number of the last line in the buffer). This is what `%L` normally shows.

The search pattern we're looking for is `\d(\d\d\d)+$` (special vim craziness removed), i.e. a digit followed by 1 or more groups of 3 digits, followed by the end of the string. Grouping is spelled `\%(` `\)` in vim, and "1 or more" is `\+`, which gives us `\d\%(\d\d\d\)\+$`. The last bit of magic is `\zs\ze`. `\zs` sets the start of the matched string; `\ze` sets the end. This works as if everything before `\zs` were a look-behind pattern and everything after `\ze` were a look-ahead pattern.

What this amounts to is: We're looking for every position in the source string that is preceded by a digit and followed by exactly N digits (where N is a multiple of 3). This works like starting at the right and going left, skipping 3 digits each time. These are the positions where we need to insert a comma.

That's what the replacement string is: `','` (a comma). Because we're matching a string of length 0, we're effectively inserting into the source string (by replacing `''` with `','`).

Finally, the `g` flag says to do this with all matches, not just the first one.

TL;DR:

- `line('$')` gives us the number of lines
- `substitute(..., '\d\zs\ze\%(\d\d\d\)\+$', ',', 'g')` adds commas where we want them
- `%{` `}` lets us embed arbitrary expressions into `statusline`

Comment: "but it looks a bit crazy" ? It's a beauty :-). Two remarks: (1) If the separator needs to be changed, it is the next to the last "\,". (2) If the separator is to be a single quote, it has to be doubled: "\'\'".